# Power on-off-on needed to boot laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, shutdown, startup, upstart

Toshiba Satellite C660 01C01H 32-bit laptop (specifications at http://bit.ly/1PPMN30)
Ubuntu 14.04.4 Trusty Tahr LTS

When I switch on the laptop the Toshiba boot screen fails to appear OR the screen turns purple then black. If I then force switch off and then switch on again immediately, the Toshiba and Ubuntu boot screens appear successively and a normal boot into Ubuntu follows. This is making me nervous that some time the laptop will eventually not boot at all.